# How can I unload a filesystem module in a RHEL 7 server in order to harden it?

Tags: filesystems, rhel, security, compression, hardening

I'm trying to harden my RHEL Linux server 7 according to the CIS guidelines, so I want to unload the cramfs.

I typed the following command:  `modprobe -n -v cramfs`

and I got the following answer:

> `insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64/kernel/fs/cramfs/cramfs.ko.xz`

instead of the one mentioned in the CIS: **install /bin/true** . I note that there is no such file in my system.

Question: what does the output mean ? In this context, how can I unmount the cramfs?

Answer (score 3):

The command you are running, `modprobe -n -v cramfs` does nothing except output what it would do as you passed `-n` which is the short option for `--dry-run`.  The output `insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64/kernel/fs/cramfs/cramfs.ko.xz` would load the `cramfs` module at that location.

You probably wanted to do `modprobe -v -r cramfs` as the `-r` flag is the short option for `--remove`.

This does not prevent the module from being loaded again on reboot, or being loaded again manually.  To prevent that, you would need to blacklist the module which is a bit more involved.

Answer (score 2):

So as GracefulRestart pointed out `modprobe -n -v cramfs` doesn't perform any changes. Another way of writing the command is `modprobe --dry-run --verbose crampfs`.

You'll notice that this is why it appears under the **audit** section in the CIS entry, and your output differs from what is expected as you are not compliant. So you can move to the remediation section for that specific check which is to create a **.conf** file under `etc/modprobe.d/` end add the following line

`install cramfs /bin/true`

and then run

`rmmod cramfs`

to unload cramfs

You should be compliant after.

---

To provide a bit more information on what's going on:

[modprobe.d man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/modprobe.d)

> install modulename command... This is the most powerful primitive: it
>   tells modprobe to run your command instead of inserting the module in
>   the kernel as normal. The command can be any shell command: this
>   allows you to do any kind of complex processing you might wish. For
>   example, if the module "fred" works better with the module "barney"
>   already installed (but it doesn't depend on it, so modprobe won't
>   automatically load it), you could say "install fred /sbin/modprobe
>   barney; /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install fred", which would do what you
>   wanted. Note the --ignore-install, which stops the second modprobe
>   from running the same install command again. See also remove below.

So instead of adding the cramfs module to the kernel we are replacing that action with `install cramfs /bin/true` which just returns a 0 value and moves on.